# Submitting paths to Google and compatibility with directions

Tags: google-maps

I work for a CSU, and we are looking into creating directions between buildings for students.

I have found that we can submit paths to Google so that they officially add them to Google maps, and we have submitted to Google mapmaker to add the visual paths and buildings.

If we submit the path information, can those paths be used for directions? Can a user put into the Google maps android app directions from Building A to Building B, and the app will supply the directions using paths on campus? If not, is there anyway to achieve this without manually creating the directions on campus?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these may eventually get incorporated into Google's directions.

Comment: What do you mean by "may eventually"? Do you mean if I do submit the information and gets accepted, it will get directions? Or Google is currently working on this feature?

Comment: Google doesn't guarantee your data will be accepted, but there's a strong possibility.